# Question about a proof of Gödel's 1st incompleteness theorem

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, predicate-logic, incompleteness

I am confused about one of the standard proofs of this theorem that I've seen. I believe it's a small thing that I missing as authors seem to skip straight through it. The proof I am referring to is the one that:

(1) encodes formulas of a logical system (such as RA) using Gödel numbering, having agreed on numerical labels for the symbols of the language. Then encodes sequences using the encoding for formulas.

(2) is able to encode '$p$ is a proof of $q$'

(3) is able to encode 'there exists a proof of $p$'

(4) creates an 'I am not provable' sentence

---

It's the nature of (2) and (3) that I am iffy about:

- are we talking about merely encoding those *statements*, or is it about whether the system able to 'check' whether $p$ is a proof of $q$, in some sort of computable way? I can see how it would do so, it decodes the list of formulas presented by $p$ using arithmetic, and checks whether they follow the rules of logic established in advance by our system, also using arithmetic.
- if the latter on my previous question, how does one get (3) from (2)? It seems authors go from checking $p$ proves $q$ to 'given $q$, we can establish whether it has a proof or not in the system' (or the system can, viewing all of this has code/arithmetic), but it's not clear to me how exactly?

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Not sure to understand... But the encoding thus not "generates" proofs. Given a number, we have a mechanical procedure (an algorithm) to check if a natural number is a code of not; if yes if it is a code of a symbol, a formula or a sequence of formulas. In the last case, "unpacking" it we can write down all the sequence of formulas and thus check if it is a derivation of the last formula or not.

Comment: the move from (2) to (3) is simple; if we have checked that $\text {Proof}(n,m)$, we apply $\exists$-intro to it and derive $\exists x \text {Proof}(x,m)$ that is $\text {Prov}(m)$ where $\text {Proof}(n,m)$ reads: "number $n$ is the code of a sequence of formulas that is a derivation with last formula having code $m$" and  $\text {Prov}(m)$ reads: "there is a derivation of formula having code $m$" (i.e. "formula having code $m$ is derivable (in the system))".

Answer (score 1):

*For simplicity, throughout I'll conflate a natural number $k$ with the corresponding numeral $\underline{k}$. Also I'll talk about $\mathsf{PA}$ instead of $\mathsf{RA}$, since I don't know what the latter is and the argument is the same for all appropriate theories.*

I'm not sure I quite understand your first question, but I believe the following will clear things up - the key point being the difference between **definability** and **provability**, and the subsequent notion of **representability** which connects the two. We have two different objects at play here: the *structure* $\mathfrak{N}=(\mathbb{N};+,\times)$, that is the standard model of arithmetic, and the *theory* $\mathsf{PA}$. "Talking about provability in $\mathsf{PA}$" amounts to two observations, which I've separated below:

---

First, we have the purely model-theoretic fact.

Fixing an appropriate Godel numbering system $\ulcorner\cdot\urcorner$, we whip up a formula $\varphi(x,y)$ in the language of arithmetic such that for each finite string of symbols $\alpha$ and each finite string of finite strings of symbols $\pi$ we have $$\mathfrak{N}\models\varphi(\ulcorner \pi\urcorner, \ulcorner\alpha\urcorner)\quad\iff\quad\mbox{$\alpha$ is a sentence and $\pi$ is a $\mathsf{PA}$-proof of $\alpha$}.$$ Note that the theory is not involved yet. $\mathsf{PA}$-provability then corresponds to the formula $$\psi(y)\equiv \exists x\varphi(x,y).$$ What this all says is that the "is-a-$\mathsf{PA}$-proof-of" relation and the "is-$\mathsf{PA}$-provable" predicate are each **definable in the structure $\mathfrak{N}$** - after "pushing through" the Godel numbering system, that is.

> **Remark:** When I say "we whip up a formula $\varphi$ such that [stuff]," I'm glossing over some serious work. This is one of the three parts of this proof of the first incompleteness theorem - the second is proving the diagonal lemma, and the third is combining the first two to get the desired result - and is the only one of the three which is actually long: the third is quite short and sweet, and the second is short (if really slippery at first). To see how to construct $\varphi$, you should read the details of the proof carefully.
>
> That said, once we have $\varphi$ we quickly get $\psi$: $\psi$ is just $\varphi$ with an existential quantifier slapped on.

---

Now we show that $\mathsf{PA}$ "understands" the formula $\varphi$ we've produced above - or at least, understands "basic facts" about $\mathsf{PA}$. Specifically, we claim that for every $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $$\mathfrak{N}\models\varphi(m,n)\quad\iff\quad \mathsf{PA}\vdash\varphi(m,n)$$ and $$\mathfrak{N}\models\neg\varphi(m,n)\quad\iff\quad\mathsf{PA}\vdash\neg\varphi(m,n).$$ In jargon, the relation $\varphi$ is **representable** in $\mathsf{PA}$.

With this in hand, we'll be able to prove the first incompleteness theorem: we prove the diagonal lemma and apply it to the formula $\neg\psi$, and then a quick analysis gives $\mathsf{PA}\not\vdash\theta$ and $\mathsf{PA}\not\vdash\neg\theta$. These last two steps are quite short. By far the longest part of the proof is constructing the desired $\varphi$.

---

A couple final comments:

- First, [Rosser's improvement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_trick) uses the same idea, except it looks at something more compicated than $\psi$. First we whip up a formula $\upsilon(x,y)$ which defines in $\mathfrak{N}$ the relation "$y$ is the Godel number of the sentence with Godel number $x$" and which is $\mathsf{PA}$-representable. This takes some work, but not nearly as much as whipping up $\varphi$. Then we apply the diagonal lemma, not to $\neg\psi(y)$, but to the more complicated formula $$\chi(y)\equiv\forall x(\varphi(x,y)\rightarrow\exists z,w(z<x\wedge\upsilon(y,w)\wedge \varphi(z, w))$$ ("for every proof of me there is a shorter disproof of me"). A minor modification of Godel's original "quick analysis" mentioned above then shows that the resulting fixed point is $\mathsf{PA}$-undecidable using only the hypothesis that $\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent (as opposed to $\omega$-consistent).
- Second, it's worth noting that when a formula $\gamma(x,y)$ is representable in $\mathsf{PA}$, the formula $\exists x\gamma(x,y)$ will not in general be representable - but it will be "half-representable." Specifically, we'll have for each $m\in\mathbb{N}$ that $$\mathfrak{N}\models\exists x\gamma(x,m)\quad\implies\quad\mathsf{PA}\vdash\exists x\gamma(x,m).$$ In particular, each $\mathsf{PA}$-provable sentence is $\mathsf{PA}$-provably $\mathsf{PA}$-provable; in the modal logic of provability this is expressed by the axiom $\Box p\rightarrow \Box\Box p.$

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think what I am having trouble understanding is, how we create a $\phi$ and $\psi$ in the language of arithmetic so that they obey the relations you wrote? And then, does $\mathfrak{N}\models  \phi(\ulcorner \pi\urcorner,\ulcorner\alpha\urcorner)$ mean "$\mathfrak{N}$ is able to construct the natural number which we know codes '$\pi$ is a $\mathsf{PA}$-proof of $\alpha$'"? Similarly for something like $\mathfrak{N}\models \psi(\alpha)$. Sorry if that's unclear, I'm sort of confusing myself too...

Comment: @user111064 First, note that $\psi$ is easy to create **after** we've created $\varphi$: it's just the formula you get from $\varphi$ by existentially quantifying out the first variable. As to building $\varphi$ itself, this takes work and is a bit tedious. You'll need to read the details of this part of the proof carefully. The standard way this is done is by showing that all primitive recursive relations, or indeed all computable relations, are representable in $\mathsf{PA}$. This is overkill but it's a very useful fact to have.

Comment: Second, I'm not sure what you mean by "the natural number which codes '$\pi$ is a $\mathsf{PA}$-proof of $\alpha$.'" The sentence $\varphi(\ulcorner\pi\urcorner,\ulcorner\alpha\urcorner)$ is either true in $\mathfrak{N}$ or false in $\mathfrak{N}$ - there's no notion of a natural number "coding" that fact in any sense. (If $\mathsf{PA}\vdash\varphi(\ulcorner\pi\urcorner,\ulcorner\alpha\urcorner)$ we **do** have a relevant notion of witness, namely "is a code for a $\mathsf{PA}$-proof of $varphi(\ulcorner\pi\urcorner,\ulcorner\alpha\urcorner)$." But this is only a thing on the "$\vdash$-side.")

Comment: Ah I think that's starting to become clearer -- I will return to the proof details then come back here, but many thanks for the very detailed answers so far, I appreciate it.

Comment: Hi, I went through the 46 relations Gödel showed, I *think* this is coming together: we construct $\phi(x,y)$ in $\mathfrak{N}$ which is true precisely when $x$ is a code for a $\mathsf{PA}$-proof of a statement coded by $y$. $\mathfrak{N}$ is a model of $\mathsf{PA}$, so we can view this as $\mathsf{PA}$ being able to make proof-statements about $\mathsf{PA}$. Am I only the right lines?